# Batch file not logging SQL errors

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

I am trying to execute 4000+ (about 140GB) scripts using the sqlcmd utility.

The reason for doing that is all export options from SQL Server 2017 to 2008 failed me miserably with errors, so I decided to script entire database using 'Generate Scripts' in SSMS, then executing all of the generated scripts via batch file and logging every single error so I can pinpoint what the issue is (or isn't) in every single script.

So far I managed to determine that 2008 doesn't really like the date formats in some tables, which is weird, because said DB was exported earlier this year from SQL SRV 2008 to 2017.

Anyway, the bach script I wrote goes like this:

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do (

if not %errorlevel% == 0 echo %errorlevel% >> errorlog.txt 2>&1
if %errorlevel% == 0 sqlcmd /S SQLINSTANCE /d DBNAME -E -i"%%G"

)

pause
```

The script executes properly (inserting 1 line at a time) with an exception of creating and appending "errorlog.txt" - this file isn't even created in a process, and when I tried to create it manually nothing was appended to this file. When I tried to create "successlog.txt" in the 4th line, the file was created and appended properly.

Does anyone have any guidance regarding the steps I could take now to make it work, please?

Comment: You are checking [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) (actually wrongly due to lack of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), but of what command?

Comment: I want to check the errorlevel of said SQL scripts performing in loop. I'm really new to the batch files so I put it together this way

Comment: `for %%G in (*.sql) do ( … )` *enumerates* (or lists or loops through) the SQL scripts but it does *not* execute them, therefore there is no `ErrorLevel` value…

Comment: in that case - what would be the best way to get ErrorLevel value from sql cmd, please?

Comment: _doesn't really like the date formats_ that is likely a false assumption and a "jump to conclusions". More likely is that your environments were not installed with the identical set of options and your code makes assumptions about **the format** of date literals. But I assume that you actually store dates in one of the related datatypes and not as strings or numbers.

Comment: what I meant by that was the following error message, sorry for not being specific earlier:

Comment: Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 70: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: followed by this error:

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 70: There was an error with Destination 348 - DIRPARTYINTERNALORGANIZATI2216.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[VALIDTODATETIME] on Destination 348 - DIRPARTYINTERNALORGANIZATI2216.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: You probably don't need the errorlevel check on the same line as sqlcmd.  If you want to know if sqlcmd causes an error, move the the other errorlevel check to the line AFTER sqlcmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a subtask inside your BAT-file, and check the errorlevel there. Here's how:

```
@Echo Off
:: Making sure the errorlevel is zero by listing all files in current folder 
:: without showing them.
dir >Nul 2>&1
:: This loop calls the subtask with the G-parameter, ie. the SQL-file path.
for %%G in (*.sql) do (
   call :my_subtask "%%~G"
)
:: Skipping to the end -section.
goto :end

:my_subtask
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 echo %errorlevel% >> errorlog.txt 2>&1
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 sqlcmd /S SQLINSTANCE /d DBNAME -E -i "%~1"
:: NOTE the path of the SQL-file is now in the %1 -parameter.
:: It is good practice to use the "%~1" notation.
:: 
:: Returning to for-loop.
goto :EOF

:end
@Echo On
```

However, I'd code the subtask to a bit differently, like this:

```
:my_subtask
@Echo on
sqlcmd /S SQLINSTANCE /d DBNAME -E -i "%~1" >> successlog.txt 2>>errorlog.txt
@Echo off
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
   Echo %~0 The subtask calling %~1 failed, errorlevel was %errorlevel% 
)
goto :EOF
```